# phonegap cordova facebook plugin JSON Error on failed Login

Tags: android, facebook, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I just wanted to test that this [plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) works, which I am failing miserably to do. Been spending >48 hours on this now and definitely need help.

I have a very simple setup. I am using ionic/angularjs. For those of you who are not familiar with these, I don't believe it is relevant, but I include this so that you are aware of my set up (and the odd syntax of a `$scope` variable...)

Basically what you see below is a login method that when invoked, executes `facebookConnectPlugin.login`. I ordered the parameters `(permissions,successCallback,failCallback`) which I believe is the correct order as opposed to what shows up in the docs.

My `successCallback` function simply gives an alert that a successful login occurred and gives out the accessToken. My `failCallback` function just gives an alert that login failed and gives the response.

When I run the code on my android device and click login, it fails to login and the response variable is just a string that says JSON Error. No other information. I'm completely lost and hoping someone can tell me what the issue is.

I've followed the android guide step by step with no errors so I would assume that I should be able to use the plugin. Anyone know why it's not working??? Anything I can do to further trouble shoot this?

```
function loginctrl($scope){

$scope.login = function(){

facebookConnectPlugin.login('public_profile,email,user_friends',
  function(response){
  alert("success!"+response.status);
  if (response.status=="connected"){
    console.log(response.authResponse.userID+" "+response.authResponse.accessToken);
  }
},function(response){
  console.error("I'm an error" + response);
  alert("failed!"+response);
});
 }
}
```

**EDIT:** It looks like the error `JSON Error` comes from a failure to execute the `login` action for the plugin. Specifically:

```
login: function (permissions, s, f) {
        cordova.exec(s, f, "FacebookConnectPlugin", "login", permissions);
    },
```

And that `cordova.exec` function executes the below. Pay attention to the first line which says `throws JSONException`. When a plugin throws a JSONException, it sends back an error saying JSON Error. Therefore the below plugin has an error in it somewhere...Still investigating to figure out what it is...

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    if (action.equals("login")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "login FB");
        // Get the permissions
        String[] arrayPermissions = new String[args.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length(); i++) {
            arrayPermissions[i] = args.getString(i);
        }

        List<String> permissions = null;
        if (arrayPermissions.length > 0) {
            permissions = Arrays.asList(arrayPermissions);
        }

        // Get the currently active session
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        // Set a pending callback to cordova
        loginContext = callbackContext;
        PluginResult pr = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
        pr.setKeepCallback(true);
        loginContext.sendPluginResult(pr);

        // Check if the active session is open
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // Reauthorize flow
            boolean publishPermissions = false;
            boolean readPermissions = false;
            // Figure out if this will be a read or publish reauthorize
            if (permissions == null) {
                // No permissions, read
                readPermissions = true;
            }
            // Loop through the permissions to see what
            // is being requested
            for (String permission : arrayPermissions) {
                if (isPublishPermission(permission)) {
                    publishPermissions = true;
                } else {
                    readPermissions = true;
                }
                // Break if we have a mixed bag, as this is an error
                if (publishPermissions && readPermissions) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (publishPermissions && readPermissions) {
                callbackContext.error("Cannot ask for both read and publish permissions.");
            } else {
                // Set up the new permissions request
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(cordova.getActivity(), permissions);
                // Set up the activity result callback to this class
                cordova.setActivityResultCallback(this);
                // Check for write permissions, the default is read (empty)
                if (publishPermissions) {
                    // Request new publish permissions
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                } else {
                    // Request new read permissions
                    session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Initial login, build a new session open request.

            // - Create a new session and set the application ID
            session = new Session.Builder(cordova.getActivity()).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            // - Create the request
            Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(cordova.getActivity());
            // - Set the permissions
            openRequest.setPermissions(permissions);
            // - Set the status change call back
            openRequest.setCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    onSessionStateChange(state, exception);
                }
            });

            // Can only ask for read permissions initially
            session.openForRead(openRequest);
        }
        return true;

 // Other statements below to handle when the execute is not 'login'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And I'm a noob.

My issue was that my permissions was a string like `'public_profile,email,user_friends'`. The correct type was an array like `['public_profile','email','user_friends']`.